# Difference of (Object*) and (id) in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, object

Help me please to find out what's the difference between these two code snippets:
(In the snippets Foo is a class derived from Object declared in objc/Object.h)

```
// Snippet 1
Object* o = [Foo new];
[o free];

// Snippet 2
id o = [Foo new];
[o free];
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Thanks for the helpful answers! Let me share a link that I found, maybe it'll help those, who meets the same question like me, and want to understand it better:
[id_vs_NSObject](http://unixjunkie.blogspot.com/2008/03/id-vs-nsobject-vs-id.html).

Comment: This is irrelevant, but you'll probably want to inherit from `NSObject` instead of `Object`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`id` can be anything and can respond to any message in the system without warning, as it could be of any type. `Object *` (do you mean `NSObject *`?) is strongly typed--the compiler assumes it only responds to methods that `Object` is known to respond to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! (I mean under Object the class declared in <objc/Object.h>)

Comment: Yeah. `Object` is the old root class from the NeXTSTEP era, which has since been replaced by `NSObject`. For some reason, `Object.h` is still distributed with Objective-C.

Comment: You should not use `Object` for new development. `NSObject` should be your root class.